# Como executar ações em determinado tempo usando Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, expressões-lambda, multithreading

Em meu projeto gostaria de criar alertas que executem á cada determinado intervalo ou em uma determinada data, Alguma maneira de fazer, usando o minimo de memória possível?

Comment: você está falando em executar uma tarefa agendada? rodar todo dia? uma vez por semana? de hora em hora?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem algumas alternativas para rodar uma tarefa agendada.

Lembrando  que para fazer isso recomendo isolar o que você quer executar em uma [rake task](http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial), assim a chamada é acessível de forma mais fácil pelo console.

1) Utilizar o CRON do sistema operacional, que você pode fazer o agendamento pelo SO e ele vai executar um comando conforme a agenda especificada, no ambiente RUBY tem a gem [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) que ajuda nesse processo, mas vale a pena ler a respeito de *crontab* do linux

2) Você pode usar o sidekiq para fazer o agendamento existe uma gem [sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq) que faz esse agendamento atrelado ao sidekiq

3) Se você vai utilizar um PAAS como o heroku eles, possuem ferramentas para fazer esse agendamento por meio da plataforma deles, já que o programador não possui tanto acesso ao SO.